# Telerik.WebControls.RadAjaxManager cause dropw down list not fire handler

Tags: telerik

I have a front end code look like below

< asp:dropdownlist id="cbo" runat="server" CssClass="combobox" AutoPostBack="True"    Width="100%" >
       < asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="A">A
       < asp:ListItem  Value="B">B
< /asp:dropdownlist>

< rada:RadAjaxManager id="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    < AjaxSettings>
            < rada:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="cbo">
        < UpdatedControls>
                            < rada:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="cbo" />
                  < /UpdatedControls>
            < /rada:AjaxSetting>
         < /AjaxSettings>
< /rada:RadAjaxManager >

In my code behind, I have the handler for the dropdownlist

Private Sub cbo_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbo.SelectedIndexChanged

textBox1.text = cbo.selectedvalue
End Sub

But the drop down do not fire the handler when it is change.  When I remove the telerik radajaxmanager, it will fire.   Any one have idea why this will happen. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The handler is probably fired, but to set text in the textbox you have to add its ID (textBox1) in the UpdatedControls collection of the ajax manager setting.

Comment: Hi Dick, I have try added the text box in the updatedcontrols but it still not fire the drop down list.  I'm using RadAjax.Net2, version 2007.  Do you have any idea?  Please advice.  thanks a lot

Comment: That's odd..I do use the new RadAjax for ASP.NET AJAX and everything works properly when I tested the case locally.